# Exporting large HAR file from Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, har

In the network tab within the Chrome Dev Tools, I have a large amount of HTTP requests that I would like to export into a HAR to analyze. I've tried to export the HAR with the export button, and I've tried the "Save all as HAR with content" option as well, but both result in a 0byte HAR file when downloaded. I've exported HARs in the past, but I guess they've never been as large so they have succeeded without issue. For reference, the network tab shows:

- 9262 requests
- 8.6 MB transferred
- 21.8 MB resources

Anyone have any experience in exporting large HAR files? Is there a way to build a script that could export this?

Comment: Ended up trying this on Firefox and it was able to export large HAR files. Not sure why Chrome wasn't able to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try webQsee (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webqsee-web-sniffer-recor/gamdpfnfkjknkimfbboonmgdfnondfme?hl=de), it is able to handle large amounts of data.

In addition to HAR export, you can also export so called "Behavior Reports" that contain not only the network communication but also console output and the screen video for later analysis.